# Animating a view over a path between two points?

Tags: android

Im looking to create an animation similar to the one in the link attached. What is the best way to achieve this type of animation effect? [Animation Video Link](https://vimeo.com/221865688)

Edit: Im looking for solutions which work for API Level 16+

Answer (score 1):

You can create a quadratic bezier curve on a path and animates view along it combined with a scale animation

For compatibility below API 21, check http://nineoldandroids.com/

```
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(startX, startY);
path.quadTo(controlX, controlY, finalX, finalY);
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, view.X, view.Y, path).start();
```

To draw the path, the documentation say :

```
void quadTo (float x1, 
                float y1, 
                float x2, 
                float y2)
```

**Add a quadratic bezier from the last point, approaching control point (x1,y1), and ending at (x2,y2). If no moveTo() call has been made for this contour, the first point is automatically set to (0,0).**

Comment: Is this supported on API level 16?

Comment: How do i calculate controlX and controlY if all i have is start Point and end Point

Comment: controlX and controlY is the approaching control point in order to curve the path. No need to calculate, just try some value